# Cannot Generate Bibliography with TeXworks

Tags: bibtex, texworks

I've read the similar questions with no avial.  Any help would be appreciated!

Using TeXworks on Windows 7.  Have

`tex_file.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\cite{merton80}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{bib_file}
\end{document}
```

and `bib_file.bib`:

```
@article{merton80,
author = ``Robert C. Merton'',
title = ``On Estimating the Expected Return on the Market'',
year = ``1980'',
journal = ``Journal of Financial Economics'',
volume = ``8'',
pages = ``323--361''
}
```

Attempts included running `pdfLaTeX+MakeIndex+BibTeX` selected in the `Typeset` command, and running in turn, `pdfLaTeX` on `tex_file.tex`, `BibTeX` on `tex_file.aux`, `pdfLaTeX` on `tex_file.tex` and again `pdfLaTeX` on `tex_file.tex`.  Both resulted in the same `pdf`:
[image]

When I open `tex_file.bbl`, it contains

```
\begin{thebibliography}{1}

\bibitem{merton80}


\end{thebibliography}
```

Comment: Wrong format in the bibtex data, use the `"` around the data entry, not ` `` ... ''`. Bibtex show give error or warning about this, but some editors never inform the user when there is bibtex warnings or errors

Comment: @Mico, sorry, it was `.bib` for compilation.  Typo.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Remove the `` '' and put curly brackets around the arguments

like

> author = {Robert C. Merton},

if you want a part to be exactly like you entered, you may choose another set of brackets

> author = {{Robert} C. Merton},

this will not get abbreviated to R. C. Merton (independent from bib-style). This is also needed, if you need special characters or commands, say

> author = {Robert C. Mert{\" o}n}

Comment: It is *absolutely not the case* that writing `author = {{Robert} C. Merton}` will keep the first name from being abbreviated to "R.".  Please correct your write-up immediately.

Answer (score 1):

This works just fine, the format states that you should use either `{...}` or `"..."` around entries.

```
\begin{filecontents}{bib_fileX.bib}
@article{merton80,
author = "Robert C. Merton",
title = "On Estimating the Expected Return on the Market",
year = "1980",
journal = "Journal of Financial Economics",
volume = "8",
pages = "323--361" 
}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\cite{merton80}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{bib_fileX}
\end{document}
```

Comment: teXworks automatically changes double quotes to two single quotes.  Do you know how I can stop this?  Manually typing in two single quotes didn't work, either

Comment: @bcf Use braces instead, seems simpler than hacking around at a different site `title= {Walzing wombats are happy}`

Comment: @bcf usually you just type it twice to get the _real_ character

Comment: @bcf - You can disable the setting in TeXworks that replaces double quotes with pairs of single quotes.